# Why Gson is not making my POJO pretty print json?

Tags: json, gson

I have googled and studied but I don't know why Gson is not printing out my POJO test class in json format.  Could someone tell me why?  Thanks.

Here's my snippet of code :

```
       ' public class User implements Serializable { 
 private user_id;
 private userName;
 private List<String>FruitList;
 getter and setter
 String to String


 public class TestPrintJson {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    User u = new User();
    u.setName("Prince Louis");
    User.setFruitList(Arrays.asList("apple", "pear"));
    String name = u.getName();
    List<String> JFruits = User.getFruitList();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    gson.toJson(u);
    System.out.println(u);
    System.out.println(u.getName());    
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(JFruit); '
```

And the printout I get is

```
    'model.User@59db6a41
     Prince Louis
     ["apple","pear"]'
```

My pom.xml contains

```
        '<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>'
```

Comment: [toJson](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson-java.lang.Object-) method returns `JSON`. It does not change your `POJO` magically to `JSON`. Try: `System.out.println(gson.toJson(u));`

Comment: It is not working on System.out.println(gson.toJson(JFruit);